# Display both unavailable and available booking time slot and disable the booked time slots

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to display all time  slots for a selected date and room. I'm using IsBooked property in TimeSlot class to indicate that the time slot is booked.

From the result that I have, it only disables the check box for the last record from the query. I want to disable all the time slots that is in the bookings database so that it cannot be double booked.

In BookingsController:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult TestTimeSlot(BookingsViewModel searchViewModel)
{
    IEnumerable<Booking> _booking = _context.Bookings
        .Where(b => b.RoomId == searchViewModel.RoomId)
        .Where(b => b.BookDate == searchViewModel.BookDate)
        .Include(b => b.Building)
        .Include(b => b.Room)
        .Include(b => b.TimeSlot)
        .OrderBy(b => b.TimeSlotId)
        .ToList();

    IEnumerable<TimeSlot> _timeSlot = _context.TimeSlots.ToList();

    foreach (var slot in _timeSlot)
    {
        foreach(var book in _booking)
        {
            if (slot.Id != book.TimeSlotId)
                slot.IsBooked = false;
            else
                slot.IsBooked = true;
        }
    }

    var viewModel = new BookingsViewModel
    {
        TimeSlots = _timeSlot,
        ConfirmedBookings = _booking,
        BuildingId = searchViewModel.BuildingId,
        RoomId = searchViewModel.RoomId,
        BookDate = searchViewModel.BookDate
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

In TimeSlot.cs:

```
public class TimeSlot
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Start Time")]
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "End Time")]
    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }

    public bool IsBooked { get; set; }
}
```

In TestTimeSlot.cshtml:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.TimeSlots)
{
    if (item.IsBooked == true)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartTime)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndTime)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    else
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartTime)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndTime)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

[Result: It only disabled the time slot at 16:30:00 while there are a couple of other records for that selected room and date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dLjF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that after you've found a booking which matches the timeslot, and have set `IsBooked` to `true`, you carry on looking through the list of bookings. Therefore when it comes to the next booking in the list, which doesn't match, the code will set `IsBooked` to `false` again! (And hopefully you can see why it works only for the last booking, because there are no other bookings left to reset the record.)

The fix should be simple - when you've found a match, just end the loop using `break;`. Control will then pass to the line after the end of the `foreach`, and no more bookings will be tested.

```
if (slot.Id != book.TimeSlotId)
  slot.IsBooked = false;
else {
  slot.IsBooked = true;
  break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This has solved my issue. I knew something was wrong with the nested loop. Thanks again.